# Tkinter Grid "Sticky" Doesn't Work With Grid Propagate

Tags: python, tkinter

Simplified version of an issue I'm having. The following code produces this output:

```
from tkinter import *

# init root
root = Tk()

# get window size
windowWidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
windowHeight = root.winfo_screenheight()

# create green frame
greenFrame = Frame(root,width=windowWidth, height=windowHeight/2, borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness = 0, bg='green')
greenFrame.grid_propagate(0) # fixed size
greenFrame.grid(row=0, column = 0)

# create blue canvas inside green frame
blueCanvas = Canvas(greenFrame, width=windowWidth/5, height=windowHeight/2, borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness = 0, bg='blue')
blueCanvas.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky = 'e') # display it on the right side

# run loop
root.mainloop()
```

[image: Output of Above Code]

The blue canvas is set in the green frame. My question is, why does the blue canvas not appear on the right side of the green frame, when it is set with sticky = 'e' in the grid call?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you think Sticky does?

Comment: I was under the impression it moves the widgets position to the specified side when it's parent widget is of a larger size

Comment: Check [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_grid.htm#:~:text=sticky%20%E2%88%92%20What%20to%20do%20if,cell%20to%20which%20widget%20sticks.)

Comment: I gave the frame a size of 100x100 and the canvas a size of 50x50 and the blue square (canvas) still ends up in the top left corner of the green frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, why does the blue canvas not appear on the right side of the green frame, when it is set with sticky = 'e' in the grid call?

You placed the blue canvas in column 0, which is going to start at the far left of the green frame. You gave it a width of 1/5th of the window width so that's as much space as `grid` allocates for it. The other 4/5ths of the window are unused by grid.

Comment: ok, so grid propagate maintains the original dimensions of the frame, but does not make it usable by the grid call for child widgets? Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: @JasonEllis: I don't know what you mean by "does not make it usable". `grid_propagate` has nothing to do with making space usable or not. If you want the frame on the right, the easiest way is to use `pack`. Or, continue to use `grid` and either configure column 0 to take all of the space or add it to some other columns and configure the other columns to take up the remaining space.

Comment: Ah ok, I was able to get what I wanted by switching `greenFrame.grid_propagate(0)` to `greenFrame.pack_propagate(0)` and packing the blue canvas instead of using `grid`. I realize now the propagate method refers to the children widgets, not the parent's. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Brian Oakley out of curiosity, how would I configure a column to take up all remaining space using grid? I don't see this option in the docs

Comment: @JasonEllis: you can use `grid_columnconfigure` to give one or more columns a `weight`. Grid will then distribute any extra space to the other columns relative to their weights.

Comment: perfect, thank you for your help!